# Django Sessions not saving between different views/api's

Tags: reactjs, django, debugging, session, backend

the session data isnt saving from one view to another:
in one view I have this:

```
try:
      df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
      request.session['dataframe'] = df.to_json()
```

Then in another view:

```
       if 'dataframe' not in request.session:
        print("Session is Currently Empty")

        df_json = request.session.get('dataframe')  # Access file from session cache

     if not df_json:
        print('not df_json')
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'No data available'}, status=404)
```

The settings/Middleware should be right. and I added additional lines like .save and modify = true and still nothing.

this is my first time using django, if anyone has tips or advice pls lmk